# SCSS CSS breakpoints in svelte for responsivity problem

Tags: css, sass, svelte, responsive, sveltekit

I have defined my breakpoints in app.scss. The singe condition breakpoints works as intended, but the one where is in condition minimal and maximal width that is probably the problem atleast according to the error: Identifier is expected.

the place -> '(min-width: 567px) and (max-width: 767px)'.

In bellow are code and images what I tried and discovered and hopefully the problem will be fixed and I will learn something from it.

Thank you for your time.

First my code. Here I define breakpoints and mixin so I can use it in app. The mixin takes as input the breakpoint key like xs, sm etc.

app.scss file

```
// screen sizes media queries
$breakpoints: (
  'xs': 'max-width: 575.98px',
  'sm': '(min-width: 567px) and (max-width: 767px)',
  'md': '(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)',
  'lg': '(min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)',
  'xl': '(min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1399px)',
  'xxl': 'min-width: 1400px',
);

// mixin that takes as input breakpoint names such as xs, sm etc.
@mixin breakpoint($user-value) {
  $my-map: map-get($breakpoints, $user-value);
  @if $my-map {
    @media (#{$my-map}) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @error "Breakpoint #{$user-value} is not defined";
  }
}
```

Usage of created mixin in +page.svelte file

```
<style lang="scss">
:global(body) {
  background-size: 100%;
  @include breakpoint(xs) {
    background-color: red;
  }
  @include breakpoint(sm) {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  @include breakpoint(md) {
    background-color: green;
  }
  @include breakpoint(lg) {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  @include breakpoint(xl) {
    background-color: white;
  }
  @include breakpoint(xxl) {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
</style>
```

And this is how error looks like:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utrfs.png)

Also I runned the code in codepen and there is working the same code:
[same code in codepen working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ujiv.png)

So thank you in advance for your suggestions.